# Uncaught Error: The route "_wdt" does not exist

Tags: symfony, orocommerce

I'm currently working on a project based on Oroplatform and I'm facing a weird issue.

I followed all the steps describe in the documentation related to the "Developement Environnement" : https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/docker-and-symfony/

Everything has worked perfectly during the installation, I can log in to the admin panel but when I try to move through dashboard pages, I have to force reload because I've got the following issue in the console :

**Uncaught Error: The route "_wdt" does not exist.**

- My routing_dev.yml

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

- the output of the command : `php bin/console debug:router | grep wdt`

```
_wdt                                                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
```

Comment: The route name should be _wdt.  Somewhere along the line you managed to change the name.  Might want to delete the cache directory and see if that helps.

Comment: My bad I just miscopy the console output.. the route name is **_wdt**. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Are you sure, that you have correct `env`?

Comment: Yes my `.env` was correct.
Finally, it came from the command to install oroplatform. I have to specify the `dev` environment instead of `prod`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error. My error is like:

[image]

My Profiler couldn't load. I used `php bin/console cache:clear` to solve this problem.